# How to create custom sort function with complicated logic?

Tags: python, sorting, oop

I'm try to sort a list of objects based on some non-trivial comparison logic, but finding it difficult because in Python the custom sort function takes only 1 argument. In Java, for example, the sort function would have references to `object1` and `object2`, making it straightforward to compare them.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, char, num, pt_type):
        self.char = char
        self.num = num
        self.pt_type = pt_type  # 'start' or 'end'

    def __str__(self):
        return str([self.char, str(self.num), self.pt_type])
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

arr = [Point('C', 1, 'end'), Point('C', 9, 'start'),
       Point('B', 7, 'end'), Point('B', 2, 'end'),
       Point('A', 3, 'start'), Point('A', 6, 'start')]

def my_sort(key):
    # Sort by first element (letter). 
    #
    # If the letter is the same, fallback to sorting by the
    # 2nd element (number), but the logic of this comparison depends
    # on `pt_type`:
    #   -If Point1 and Point2 both have type 'start', pick the higher number first.
    #   -If Point1 and Point2 both have type 'end', pick the lower number first.
    #   -If Point1 and Point2 have different types, pick the 'start' type first.
    return key.char

print(sorted(arr, key=my_sort))
```

The expected sorted order should be:

```
[Point('A', 6, 'start'), Point('A', 3, 'start')
 Point('B', 2, 'end'), Point('B', 7, 'end'),
 Point('C', 9, 'start'), Point('C', 1, 'end')]
```

I don't know how to even start implementing the required logic, so I would be grateful for a push in the right direction.

Comment: Is the sort order correct? Shouldn't Point('C', 9, 'start') be the first? As far as I understood all 'start' nodes must come first, and the tie break is the highest

Comment: @DanielMesejo The sort is primarily by the *letter*, if the letters of 2 items are the same then we fall back to the secondary criteria which is that block of logic that depends on `pt_type`. So 'C' would come after any 'A' or 'B' items no matter what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make sorting a property of your class, then use `sorted`. The benefit of this method: for no additional effort, you are able to compare objects with each other via comparison operators such as `>`, `<`, `==`.

#### Specify `__eq__` and `__lt__` methods

At a minimum you should specify `__eq__` and `__lt__` methods:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, char, num, pt_type):
        self.char = char
        self.num = num
        self.pt_type = pt_type  # 'start' or 'end'

    def __str__(self):
        return str([self.char, str(self.num), self.pt_type])

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.char == other.char and self.pt_type == other.pt_type

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.char != other.char:
            return self.char < other.char
        if (self.pt_type == 'start') and (other.pt_type == 'start'):
            return self.num > other.num
        elif (self.pt_type == 'end') and (other.pt_type == 'end'):
            return self.num < other.num
        else:
            return self.pt_type == 'start'
```

Adding other comparison methods such as `__gt__`, `__ge__`, etc, may be simplified via [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering):

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Point:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        # initialization logic
    def __eq__(self, other):
        # as before
    def __lt__(self, other):
        # as before
```

#### Example

```
arr = [Point('C', 1, 'end'), Point('C', 9, 'start'),
       Point('B', 7, 'end'), Point('B', 2, 'end'),
       Point('A', 3, 'start'), Point('A', 6, 'start')]

print(sorted(arr))

[['A', '6', 'start'],
 ['A', '3', 'start'],
 ['B', '2', 'end'],
 ['B', '7', 'end'],
 ['C', '9', 'start'],
 ['C', '1', 'end']]
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct and right way to solve the problem in python3 . Maybe I would also mention https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering , which maybe is needed. Thanks

Comment: @DBedrenko, Excellent point, have added the trivial example as in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the following `key` function:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, char, num, pt_type):
        self.char = char
        self.num = num
        self.pt_type = pt_type  # 'start' or 'end'

    def __str__(self):
        return str([self.char, str(self.num), self.pt_type])

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


arr = [Point('C', 1, 'end'), Point('C', 9, 'start'),
       Point('B', 7, 'end'), Point('B', 2, 'end'),
       Point('A', 3, 'start'), Point('A', 6, 'start')]


def key(p):
    return p.char, int(p.pt_type != 'start'), p.num if p.pt_type == 'end' else -1 * p.num


result = sorted(arr, key=key)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['A', '6', 'start'], ['A', '3', 'start'], ['B', '2', 'end'], ['B', '7', 'end'], ['C', '9', 'start'], ['C', '1', 'end']]
```

The key function creates a tuple to be used as key, the first element is the letter, the second element is 0 if the node is of type 'start', 1 if is of type 'end'. The last element is negative if it is of type 'start', positive if it is of type 'end'.

Comment: @coldspeed I see, but I believe the second numbe should be negative only when if of type start, right?

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't notice that was the requirement.

Comment: @jpp Updated the answer!

Comment: Thanks for your idea. This seems like a hack, and seems to make the situation more complicated than it already is, but I see that `cmp()` is deprecated in Python3 so I don't know what to think anymore...

Comment: I see, you could use @jpp solution.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `cmp` argument to `sorted` which takes a comparison function of 2 arguments:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted

For your reference, the `key` function would compute a derived value from each item being sorted and sort according to that value, e.g. to sort a list of pairs by the second value in the pair you could do: `sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: Ah didn't know there was `cmp(obj1, obj2)`, now I know how I would implement the logic, thank you.

Comment: FYI `cmp()` is deprecated in python3